# How can I set up my domain to point different hosts?

Tags: dns, hosting, host, squarespace

I have a website on square space with a domain  example.com ,I want specific URLS to point to another host.

like 
example.com/page1 
example.com/page4 
example.com/page8

to be in my new host but have the same domain.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the same domain and have multiple servers serving the content, something like:

```
example.com/page1 ---> host serving page1
example.com/page4 ---> host serving page4
..
```

If this is the case one quick way to achieve this is by using a CND, something like [AWS CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_Origin.html) and defines multiple origins.

Every  `/path` can be an origin and all of them are server thought your main domain `example.com`